# why this TypeError msg in python3 script checking files' timestamps?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, debugging, typeerror

Can you please help me with this task? What am I getting wrong?

I'm on a Windows 11 machine and I'm trying to write a python 3.11 script that:

1. sorts through a list of screenshots contained in a given folder,
2. selects only those whose creation (or modification date, doesn't matter) is older than a certain given date, let's say the 30th of April 2022,
3. adds these files (only these) to an 'old files' list.
4. Finally moves these old files to the Trash can.

Please find below my attempt.

The interpreter returns a TypeError msg, particularly with the latter part of this line of code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ...
>
> if modified.date() <= **dt.date(2022,4,30)**:
>
> TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import os , send2trash, timedelta

myuser=os.getlogin()

# set paths
archivePath=rf"C:\Users\{myuser}\Pictures\Saved Pictures\2022.11.zip"
logPath=rf"C:\Users\{myuser}\Downloads\screenshots\TEST"

# a list of ONLY old files based on 'last modified' time (since Epoch).
if os.path.isfile(archivePath):
    print("Archive already exists, deleting copies in TEST folder.\n")
    os.chdir(logPath)
    old=[]
    for file in sorted(os.listdir(logPath)):
        modified=dt.fromtimestamp(os.stat(file).st_mtime) ## a float nr?
        ## conditions to be met: 
        if modified.date() <= dt.date(2022,4,30):
           old.append(file)
        else:
            print(str(file), ': conditions NOT met.')
    ## mv to trashcan
    numberFiles=len(old)
    print(f"Deleting {numberFiles} file.")
    for oldFile in old:
        send2trash.send2trash(oldFile)
else:
    print('No files deleted.')
```

Answer (score 0):

managed to get it working by modifying these lines:

```
import datetime
...

myDate=datetime.datetime(2022,4,30)

...

    for file in sorted(os.listdir(logPath)):
        modified=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(file).st_mtime)
        ## conditions to be met:
        if modified <= myDate:
            old.append(file)
```

Essentially, I was getting wrong the `datetime.datetime` methods